# Powershell/Batch convert fixed length to comma or pipe delimited

Tags: batch-file, powershell

Input:

```
1116559   P1303251287   20130325225906CD   13013822   1   0000
1104220   P1303250282   20130325070119CD              1   0000
1064743   P1303251094   20130325191600CD              0   0000
1100819   P1303250369   20130325091722CD              0   0000
1101405   P1303250051   20130325010740CD              2   0000
```

What I get from my attempt:

```
$lines = Get-Content "filenamehere.txt"
ForEach ($x in $lines) {
$y = "$($x[0..9] -join '')|$($x[10..23] -join '')|$($x[24..42] -join '')|
$($x[43..53] -    join '')|$($x[54..57] -join '')|$($x[58..61] -join '')|
$($x[126..138] -join '')"
$z = $y -join '|'
Write-Output $z | Out-File -FilePath "foo.txt" -Append}
```

I get:

```
1116559   |P1303251287   |20130325225906CD   |13013822   |1   |0000|
1104220   |P1303250282   |20130325070119CD   |           |1   |0000|
1064743   |P1303251094   |20130325191600CD   |           |0   |0000|
1100819   |P1303250369   |20130325091722CD   |           |0   |0000|
1101405   |P1303250051   |20130325010740CD   |           |2   |0000|
```

I don't mind the trailing spaces as long as I can get into this format. But "Get-Content" parse my data into an array and importing to SQL gives me an error. Question is, how can I convert this into CSV?

Output should be:

```
1116559|P1303251287|20130325225906CD|13013822|1|0000
1104220|P1303250282|20130325070119CD|        |1|0000
1064743|P1303251094|20130325191600CD|        |0|0000
1100819|P1303250369|20130325091722CD|        |0|0000
1101405|P1303250051|20130325010740CD|        |2|0000
```

Comment: Thought the question was bash, in which case `sed -r 's|(.{10})(.{11})(.{19})(.{14})(.{8})|^\1^\2^\3^\4^\5^|g' | sed -r 's|\^ *([^ ]+) *|^\1|g' | column -ts'^' -o'|'` would work.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do that with -replace

```
$Regex   = '(.{7})\s{3}(.{11})\s{3}(.{16})\s{3}(.{8})\s{3}(.{1})\s{3}(.{4})'
$Replace = '$1|$2|$3|$4|$5|$6'

(Get-Content "filenamehere.txt") -replace $Regex,$Replace |
 Set-Content "foo.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample you can use trim()

```
$lines = Get-Content "c:\temp\filenamehere.txt"
ForEach ($x in $lines)
 {
   $y = "$(($($x[0..9] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[10..23] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[24..42] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[43..53] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[54..57] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[58..61] -join '')).trim())|$(($($x[126..138] -join '')).trim())"
   $z = $y -join '|'
   Write-Output $z | Out-File -FilePath "c:\temp\foo.txt" -Append
 }
```

Perhaps it remove too much spaces.
I output

```
1116559|P1303251287|20130325225906CD|13013822|1|0000|
1104220|P1303250282|20130325070119CD||1|0000|
1064743|P1303251094|20130325191600CD||0|0000|
1100819|P1303250369|20130325091722CD||0|0000|
1101405|P1303250051|20130325010740CD||2|0000|
```

Which should be better on a CSV point of view.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

for /F "tokens=1-6" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   if "%%f" neq "" (
      echo %%a^|%%b^|%%c^|%%d^|%%e^|%%f
   ) else (
      echo %%a^|%%b^|%%c^|        ^|%%d^|%%e
   )
)
```

Output:

```
C:\> test.bat
1116559|P1303251287|20130325225906CD|13013822|1|0000
1104220|P1303250282|20130325070119CD|        |1|0000
1064743|P1303251094|20130325191600CD|        |0|0000
1100819|P1303250369|20130325091722CD|        |0|0000
1101405|P1303250051|20130325010740CD|        |2|0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`ConvertFrom-FixedLengths` function](http://robertwesterlund.net/post/2014/03/23/converting-fixed-column-length-text-files-into-objects-using-powershell) you could just do:

```
Get-Content "C:\input.txt" | 
    ConvertFrom-FixedLengths 10,14,19,11,4,4 -Trim | 
    Foreach { @($_.Column1, $_.Column2, $_.Column3, $_.Column4.PadLeft(8, ' '), $_.Column5, $_.Column6) -Join "|" } |
    Out-File -FilePath "c:\output.txt"
```

Or, of course, if you want to create a csv-file with the `|` character as delimiter you could just do:

```
Get-Content "C:\input.txt" | 
    ConvertFrom-FixedLengths 10,14,19,11,4,4 -Trim | 
    Select Column1, Column2, Column3, @{ N = "Column4"; E = { $_.Column4.PadLeft(8) } }, Column5, Column6 | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|"
```

Or, to make it even simpler, if you want a csv-file and don't need to pad the fourth column with spaces, you could just skip the `Select´ line in the last sample, making it into:

```
Get-Content "C:\input.txt" | 
    ConvertFrom-FixedLengths 10,14,19,11,4,4 -Trim | 
    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Output.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "|"
```

Comment: All of it returned errors: Unable to find type [ordered]...Cannot index into null array.

Comment: @user3439076: Which PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using v2.0

Comment: The version posted there only supports PowerShell version 4. It needs some alterations to support version 2. I might write an update to it later, if so, I'll post here.

Answer (score 0):

For a *decent* solution, you need to handle the content as fixed length fields, the other answers here do that.

If you know only column 4 might be blank, you can bodge it for a one-off script by replacing an 11 character space with a comma (which will do nothing on rows where column 4 has content), then replacing spaces with commas:

```
Get-Content "data.txt" | % { ($_ -replace "\s{11}", ",") -replace "\s+", "," } > out.txt
```

Sample output:

```
1116559,P1303251287,20130325225906CD,13013822,1,0000
1104220,P1303250282,20130325070119CD,,1,0000
1064743,P1303251094,20130325191600CD,,0,0000
1100819,P1303250369,20130325091722CD,,0,0000
1101405,P1303250051,20130325010740CD,,2,0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Working code..

```
CD 'C:\\FOLDERPATH\'
$filter = "FILE_NAME_*.txt" 

$columns = 11,22,32,42,54 

## DO NOT NEED TO REVERSE [array]::Reverse($columns) #too lazy to re-write array after finding out I need to iterate in reverse

$files = get-childitem ./ |where-object {$_.Name -like $filter}
$newDelimiter = '|'

foreach($file in $files)
{
    $file

    $csvFile = 'C:\\FOLDERPATH\NEW_' + $file.BaseName + '.txt'
    if (!(get-childitem ./ |where-object {$_.Name -like $csvFile})) #check whether file has been processed
    { 

        $content | ForEach {
            $line = $_
            $counter = 0
            $columns | ForEach {
                $line = $line.Insert($_+$counter, $newDelimiter)  
                $counter = $counter + 1
                }
            $line = $line.Trim($newDelimiter)
            $line
        } | set-content $csvFile
    }

}
```